# Показать/скрыть блоки по клику через slideToggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка

Столкнулся с проблемой, как по клику на кнопку показывать и скрывать ДВА дива в контейнере через slideToggle? При том что контейнеров может быть бесчисленное количество и привязку по ID не реализовать.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="stroke one"><a href="#" class="w-button">Button Text</a></div>
    <div class="stroke two"></div>
    <div class="stroke three"></div>
</div>

<style>
.stroke.two,
.stroke.three {
  display:none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.container .one a').click(function(e) {
  $('.container').not($(this).closest('.container')).find('.two, .three').hide();
  $(this).closest('.container').find('.two, .three').toggle();
});
```

```css
.stroke.two,
.stroke.three {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="stroke one"><a href="#" class="w-button">Button Text</a></div>
  <div class="stroke two">Two</div>
  <div class="stroke three">Three</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="stroke one"><a href="#" class="w-button">Button Text</a></div>
  <div class="stroke two">Two</div>
  <div class="stroke three">Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Прекрасно работает, спасибо! Не подскажете как доделать, чтоб при раскрытии одного контейнера - остальные закрывались?